# How to customize contour lines in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am preparing a contour map where I am supposed to highlight the contour line for a specific level. For Example, my contour line values are lying between -1 and 1 and I want to highlight the line corresponding to the value 0. I tried to do this using the following procedure,

```
[M,c]=contourf(longitude,latitude,delta',-1:0.2:1);
s=size(c.LevelList,2);
for i=1:s
  if (c.LevelList(i)==0)
  c.LevelWidth=2;
  end;
end;
```

However, it does nothing to the contour map. Can anyone please help me with the appropriate procedure?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest simply using `contour` on your desired levels to highlight after the initial `contourf`, like so:

```matlab
% Input.
x = linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 101);
y = x + pi;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = 0.5 * (sin(X) + cos(Y));

% Levels to plot with contourf.
levelsf = -1:0.2:1;

% Levels to highlight.
levels = [0 0.3];

figure(1);
hold on;

% Contourf all levels.
contourf(X, Y, Z, levelsf);

% Highlight levels with simple contour.
contour(X, Y, Z, levels, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

hold off;
```

For highlighting `levels = [0 0.3]`, you'll get:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks! For highlighting only the 0 contour lines I used [0 0], it worked without any issue.